# Error al pasar delegado como parametro c#

Tags: c#, delegados

Tengo una clase con el metodo y el delegado:

```
public delegate void RendererDelegate(double x1, double y1, double x2, double y2, double z);

public static void Contour(double[,] d, double[] x, double[] y, double[] z, RendererDelegate renderer){
 ///
 renderer(x1, y1, x2, y2, z[k]);
}
```

Estoy intentando llamarla desde el constructor de MainWindows.xaml.cs  pasandole los parametros:

```
double[,] test = new double[3, 2] {
            { 100, 2 },
            { 200, 3 },
            { 30, 4 }
        };

        double[] x = new double[3];

        x[0] = 2;
        x[1] = 4;
        x[2] = 7;

        double[] y = new double[3];

        y[0] = 2;
        y[1] = 4;
        y[2] = 7;

        double[] z = new double[3];

        z[0] = 2;
        z[1] = 4;
        z[2] = 7;

        RendererDelegate renderer = new();

        Conrec.Contour(test, x,y,z, renderer);
```

Necesito pasar como parametro el delegado pero este no lo acepta de forma null (que es como lo estoy haciendo, de que forma podria completar ese parametro final?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Un **delegado** es un tipo que encapsula de forma segura un método, o dicho de otra forma es una referencia a un método. Cuando se define un **delegado** lo que se hace es declarar una variable que apunta a otro método. Tu **delegado** tiene la siguiente firma o estructura:

```
public delegate void RendererDelegate(double x1, double y1, double x2, double y2, double z);
```

Es decir, tu **delegado** aceptará un método que reciba como parámetros **5** tipos **double**, y no retorne nada, ya que es **void**.

Tu estás construyendo el **delegado** pero no estás asignándole ningún método con la estructura propia del delegado (un método con **5** parámetros de tipo **double** y que no retorna nada), por lo que previamente tendrías que haber hecho algún método o métodos con la estructura que aceptará el **delegado**, por ejemplo:

```
//Método 1
public void Prueba (double x1, double y1, double x2, double y2, double z)
{
   //Código del método Prueba
}

//Método 2
public void Prueba2 (double x1, double y1, double x2, double y2, double z)
{
   //Código del método Prueba2
}

//Método 3
public void Prueba3 (double x1, double y1, double x2, double y2, double z)
{
   //Código del método Prueba3
}
```

Aquí se han declarado tres métodos con la estructura que acepta el **delegado**, donde cada uno tendrá su código especifico.

Entonces para asignar alguno de estos métodos a tu **delegado** harías:

```
RendererDelegate renderer = new(Prueba);

//También podría ser
//RendererDelegate renderer = new(Prueba2);
//RendererDelegate renderer = new(Prueba3);

//O podrías poner
//RendererDelegate renderer = Prueba;
//RendererDelegate renderer = Prueba2;
//RendererDelegate renderer = Prueba3;
```

Como ves arriba se exponen diferentes asignaciones al **delegado RendererDelegate**  de métodos que cumplen con la estructura de dicho **delegado**, y además se muestran dos formas distintas de asignar el método a algún **delegado**. Una vez que tienes un método cargado en tu **delegado** pues entonces harías:

```
Conrec.Contour(test, x,y,z, renderer);
```

Llamarías a tu **método Contour** con sus correspondientes parámetros.

Y dentro del **método Contour**:

```
public static void Contour(double[,] d, double[] x, double[] y, double[] z, RendererDelegate renderer)
{
   renderer(x1, y1, x2, y2, z[k]);
}
```

Al hacer:

```
renderer(x1, y1, x2, y2, z[k]);
```

Se ejecutaría el código del método que se cargó previamente en el **delegado**.

Revisa bien porque veo que en tus métodos tienes lo mismo parámetros de tipo **double**, como **double[]** o **double[,]** y si el método no tiene la misma estructura que acepta tu **delegado** pues habrá error.

Existen además, temas más avanzados como **delegados genéricos**, **delegados anónimos** y **eventos**, si lo deseas puedes investigar más sobre el tema en Internet.

Answer (score 1):

Prueba con poner un signo de interrogación al ultimo parámetro, esto para que acepte un valor nulo:

```
public static void Contour(double[,] d, double[] x, double[] y, double[] z, RendererDelegate? renderer){
 ///
 renderer(x1, y1, x2, y2, z[k]);
}
```

En caso de que esto no funcione, entonces intenta enviar el valor por referencia y así termine el método seguirá teniendo los valores guardados en el objeto.
Algo como esto:

```
public static void Contour(double[,] d, double[] x, double[] y, double[] z, ref RendererDelegate renderer){
 ///
 renderer(x1, y1, x2, y2, z[k]);
}
```

Y cuando llames al método:

```
RendererDelegate renderer = new();
Conrec.Contour(test, x,y,z, ref renderer);
```